# Syncing Evolution and Office365 calendar

Tags: 15.04, evolution, calendar, office365

I have used the `evolution-ews` package and successfully set up email sync to my office365 account.

The names of my calendars appear under the account in calendar view, but there are no appointments visible. If I make a new appointment in Evolution and then sync, the new appointment appears in the Office365 web interface.

What could the problem be?

Comment: I have a same problem, did you manage to get it working ?